# ArcObjects identify tool

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, select-by-attribute, visual-studio

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and developing an application using visual studio 2010 and ARCObject SDK 10.1.

I would like to use identity tool in my application and if not possible I want to execute a query on the attribute table of the map layer when a user clicks on it.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this task? From my research,I think IQuery interface may be used; however, I would like to do the query based on a mouse click event.

Comment: Are you developing a standalone application, or is this within Arcmap?

Comment: witin arcmap as addin

Comment: do you mean Identify Tool? have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

i did  as u asked me however the return cursor contains all the record rather than a single record. Please look at the code below  Please look the code , I wish to access the feature at the mouse coordinate on mouse click event. however my code below return all the records rather than a single point. any guess what is wrong.

```
IMxApplication pMxApp = null;
pMxApp = (IMxApplication)ArcMap.Application;
IMxDocument pMxDoc = null;

pMxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
if (pMxDoc.SelectedLayer == null)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("There is no layer selected. First select a time-aware layer.");
    return;
   }
IMap pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap;
IFeatureLayer feature_layer = (IFeatureLayer)pMap.get_Layer(0);
IPoint point = new PointClass();

x = pMxDoc.CurrentLocation.X; 
 y = pMxDoc.CurrentLocation.Y;
MessageBox.Show(x+ ":" + y);
point.PutCoords(x, y);

point.SpatialReference = pMap.SpatialReference;
ISpatialFilter spatial_filter = new SpatialFilterClass();
spatial_filter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
spatial_filter.Geometry = point;
 spatial_filter.GeometryField = feature_layer.FeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;
MessageBox.Show(spatial_filter.GeometryField.ToString());
IFeatureCursor feature_cursor = feature_layer.FeatureClass.Search(spatial_filter,        false);
IFeature feature = feature_cursor.NextFeature();

 while (feature != null) // here it returns the whole records rather than single point.
     {

      MessageBox.Show(feature.get_Value(3).ToString());
      feature = feature_cursor.NextFeature();
     }
   }

 }
```

Comment: You should make sure your code is tagged as code using the {} button, it's difficult to read and interpret this unformatted code

Comment: Please have a look now. thnx

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is a bit old and in VBA, however I think it should give you the result you are looking for (after converting it to .NET/C# add-in).  It basically uses a buffered search point on mouse down event, then uses a spatial filter and search cursor to return the feature.

[Find a Feature Programmatically](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/default.asp?URL=/arcobjects/9.1/Samples/ArcMap/FindFeature.htm)

Answer (score -1):

If I were doing it I would get the XY coordinate of the point clicked using a tool button. Convert these coordinates into a point geometry and feed that into an ISpatialFilter then create a cursor over the FeatureLayer where the point intersects. I've made various assumptions in that statement...

This question is better answered by the [ESRI forum](http://forums.esri.com/) as what you are asking is something that developers regularly ask about.

Comment: i did  as u asked me however the return cursor contains all the record rather than a single record. Please look at the code below